# How to change the bootstrap dropdown-submenu icon?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I am using bootstrap 2.3.2 and I make its submenus to open from left site and I put the submenu arrow icon in the left side but I don't know how to change the right arrow icon to a left one.

**Update**

This is the `li` tag that contains children:

```
<li class="dropdown">
    <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Parent1 <b class="caret">
    </b></a>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
        <li class="dropdown-submenu"><a href="#" tabindex="-1">Sub-Parent1</a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-plus"></i>&nbsp;Child1</a></li>
                <li><a href="~/User"><i class="fa fa-list"></i>&nbsp;Chiled2</a></li>
                <li class="divider"></li>
                <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-plus"></i>&nbsp;Child3</a></li>
                <li><a href="~/User"><i class="fa fa-list"></i>&nbsp;Child4</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="dropdown-submenu"><a href="#" tabindex="-1">Sub-Parent2</a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-plus"></i>&nbsp;Child1</a></li>
                <li><a href="~/User"><i class="fa fa-list"></i>&nbsp;Child2</a></li>
                <li class="divider"></li>
                <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-plus"></i>&nbsp;Child3</a></li>
                <li><a href="~/User"><i class="fa fa-list"></i>&nbsp;Child4</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
</li>
```

I make the childs to open from left site with setting `float:left` in `bootstrao.css` and for putting the arrow icon in the left side I did the same and now I just need to change the icon itself.

Comment: Please show your code

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is it:

```
.dropdown-submenu > a:after {
  display: block;
  float: left;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  margin-top: 5px;
  margin-right: -10px;
  border-color: transparent;
  border-right-color: #cccccc;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 5px 5px 5px 0;
  content: " ";
}
```

Answer (score 3):

you'll need to look at the class called `dropdown-submenu>a:after`. this is what bootstrap uses to create the arrow. it seems like a very terrible way to do it to me, it uses borders and such.

```
display: block;
float: right;
width: 0;
height: 0;
margin-top: 5px;
margin-right: -10px;
border-color: transparent;
border-left-color: #ccc;
border-style: solid;
border-width: 5px 0 5px 5px;
content: " ";
```

you'll have to take this CSS, reverse it, and then add it to your own CSS of `dropdown-submenu>a:before`

Comment: Thank your for your help. I did it with your advice.;)

Comment: Thanks! Its indeed confusing how they are setting those arrows. I want to toggle it change the direction and it seems confusing.